# Signed binary being warned as signed by unknown developer on OSx

Tags: macos, security, code-signing

I have a binary file. I released it to the customer, which is signed by a valid developer certificate. When customer is downloading that binary and trying to execute it (customer has a standard user account on Mac) the user gets a popup notification:

> signed by a unknown developer and you security setting allows installation only from Appstore

When user try to change setting obviously it ask for admin password.
How do I see if something is wrong with my developer certificate?

Another possible clue on this: After downloading the same binary, if I execute on my system, it does not give my non-admin user any warning.

**Signed binary cert chain is** :

```
Authority=Mac Developer: tommyboy

Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority

Authority=Apple Root CA
```

Comment: If the client settings are "App Store only" then even a properly signed binary isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the security settings of the computer in **System Preferences** → **Security & Privacy** are set to **Allow apps downloaded from: App Store** as shown in the error message. Regardless of how your application is signed, if it's not distributed through the App Store, Gatekeeper will show that message. To allow all other signed apps, the setting needs to be changed to ‘App Store and identified developers’.

Comment: can this setting be changed for a standard user only by same standard user? I tried to change it it ask for admin username and password.

Comment: @user3856170 The setting is system-wide and requires administrator privileges to change.

Comment: I get this that i need to change settings to "Mac App store and identified developer". I am saying the notification is ""tangocharlie" can't be opened because it is from unidetified developer". why binaries signed with my developer certificate, are being reported as from unidentified developer? could be becasue i a using ma cert wrong way? wrong purpose?wrong cert? FYI its a non-admin account(standard) even after changing the setting to Mac and identified dev, it still ask the for admin passwd.